# undefined reference to `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)' during runtime

Tags: opencv, cmake, surf, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am creating an app on the nvidia jetson nano (under ubuntu 18.04 LTS) using Qt-creator. To do so I create my own library (named recolib) which uses opencv (version 3.4.6) and then in my Qt app project I include my library.

The library compiles fine, but when I tried compiling the app it reaches 100% and then I get the following error: undefined reference to `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)'.

Note that the class where this function is called is part of my library "recolib".

I have build opencv with cmake, I have enabled non-free modules and gave the right path to it and opencv built and installed fine.

Moreover, the app works well on mac and on an ubuntu virtual machine.

Here are samples of the Cmakelist.txt of the app:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Add folder where are supportive functions
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -std=c++11 -pthread -lm")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -std=c++11 -pthread -lm")

...

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

if(OPENCV_XFEATURES2D_FOUND)
    message("xfeatures2d found")
endif()

...

SET(RECOLIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/recotracking-recolib")

include_directories("${RECOLIB_DIR}/include")
if(WIN32)
    link_directories("${RECOLIB_DIR}/build/Debug")
else()
    link_directories("${RECOLIB_DIR}/build/")
endif()

SET(RECOLIB_LIBRARY recolib)

include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

...

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE RES_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.qrc")
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES "${SRC_FOLDER}/*.cpp")
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE UI_FILES "${SRC_FOLDER}/*.ui")
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE HDR_FILES "${HDR_FOLDER}/*.h")

link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("opencv libs: ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}")
add_executable(${execName}  ${OS_BUNDLE}# Expands to WIN32 or MACOS_BUNDLE depending on OS
    ${RES_FILES} ${SRC_FILES} ${UI_FILES} ${HDR_FILES} ${META_FILES_TO_INCLUDE}
)

...

# Add the Qt5 Widgets for linking
if (APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(${execName}
        ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
        ${AppKit}
        ${CoreAudio}
        ${AudioToolbox}
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Gui
        Qt5::QuickControls2
        Qt5::MultimediaWidgets
        Qt5::Multimedia
        Qt5::MultimediaPrivate
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Sql
        ${RECOLIB_LIBRARY})
else()
    target_link_libraries(${execName}
        ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Gui
        Qt5::QuickControls2
        Qt5::MultimediaWidgets
        Qt5::Multimedia
        #Qt5::MultimediaPrivate
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Sql
        ${RECOLIB_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

And the output I get executing it under Qt-creator is the following:

```
Running "/usr/bin/cmake -E server --pipe=/tmp/cmake-Bg9h0e/socket --experimental" in /home/bookbeo-novatech/build-recotracking-app-Desktop-Release.
Starting to parse CMake project, using: "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release", "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++", "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/gcc", "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/usr", "-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake".
-std=c++11 -pthread -lm
The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Looking for pthread_create
Looking for pthread_create - not found
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
Looking for pthread_create in pthread
Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
Found Threads: TRUE 
Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable exact version "10.0") 
Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.4.6") 
xfeatures2d found
opencv libs: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cvv;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
Configuring done
Generating done
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE


CMake Project was parsed successfully.
```

So as you can see, except for some issues with pthread (but it seems unrelated to the main problem), the cmake configuration appears to be good. Opencv is found and xfeatures2d too.

But when I build the app, at the end of the compilation I get:

```
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/recotracking-app.dir/recotracking-app_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/recotracking-app.dir/recotracking-app_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_resources.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable recotracking-app
/home/bookbeo/recotracking-app/libs/recotracking-recolib/build/librecolib.a(PCB.cpp.o): In function `reco::PCB::load(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<reco::RecoPoi, std::allocator<reco::RecoPoi> >)':
CMakeFiles/recotracking-app.dir/build.make:1045: recipe for target 'recotracking-app' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/recotracking-app.dir/all' failed
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
/home/bookbeo-novatech/recotracking-app/libs/recotracking-recolib/src/PCB.cpp:47: undefined reference to `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [recotracking-app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/recotracking-app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
10:51:49: Le processus "/usr/bin/cmake" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet recotracking-app (kit : Desktop)
When executing step "CMake Build"
10:51:49: Temps écoulé : 06:59.
```

I already tried re-building opencv, it didn't change anything, and the module xfeatures2d seems to be found so I don't know where this error is coming from.

If you have any idea, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with make VERBOSE=1 to see if the code is actually linking in the OpenCV libraries

Comment: With VERBOSE=1, xfeatures2d appears in the output among all the libraries: "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.4.6"